# localhost index.html does not display

Tags: drupal

I was trying to install drupal and did the following command
based on instructions from a website.

```
sed 's/www/www\/drupal/g' default > drupal
```

which seemed to redirect to localhost/drupal when I typed localhost

Now i've uninstalled drupal and I get a 404 error when I type localhost
in the browser,  I want to undo the effect of the sed command so typing
localhost will just redirect to var/www/index.html

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You must take a look at your virtual hosts configuration file